# What does this function do? Something to do with clamping values?

Tags: c++, image-processing, exponent

I found this function somewhere, quite a while ago. I do not exactly know what it is doing. I use it to manipulate a simplex noise output (with greyscale values between 0 and 255), but would like to understand it better.

```
int ExponentFilter(int value, int cover, double sharpness)
{
    int c = value - (255 - cover);
    if(c < 0)
        c = 0;
    return 255 - ((std::pow(sharpness,c)) * 255);
}
```

I use it like:

```
ExponentFilter(n,140,0.98f)
```

Where n is my value between 0 and 255.

Comment: Have you tried running it with a variety of test data to observe its behaviour?

Comment: Well - you've got the function, just plot it.

Comment: @Sean thanks for your answer. Yes, I have; as I said I've been using it on greyscale textures generated from simplex noise, so I have an idea of what it's doing. However, I don't understand if the 0 and 255 are hardcoded for a reason or if they could potentially be variables. I don't understand exactly what this function _is_, is "Exponent Filter" the correct name for it?

Comment: @Hulk thanks for taking the time to answer. Math isn't my strong-suit. How do I plot a function, and more importantly, what would doing this tell me?

Comment: Well, you could, for example, just over a sweep over your 255 input values (just a for-loop), store output the results, drop them in a column of a table calculation program (eg. Excel) and create a graph. Then you'll see on a glance what it does for each input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cover` is how "shielded" the signal is from being totally cut off. `cover` 140 means that the 140 highest (brightest) values (116-255) can result in output > 0.

`sharpness` describes how fast the light fades. `0,98` means that the light fades about twice as fast, but the fading effect is not linear, it is reduced for darker areas.

I would expect this filter to  darken and sharpen overexposed images.

Exponentfilter is a fitting name, since the sharpness function uses exponents (pow is the exponent function).

Comment: Cheers, this is exactly what I needed to know. Are you able to provide any resources or where I can learn about graphical filters or maybe some examples of different ones?